# Add a image using Href Id , using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a wordpress website ,

Where i need to add a image before Hyper link , but i am failed to do so.

[image]

I have this for href , and i need image above these links

[image]

but i am failed , so far i tried to write css is

```
 background: url("outline.png") no-repeat 6px center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
```

but its not showing perfectly, also somepart of image going in background , i also tried Z-Index : 99999 , to show on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using **:before** element. Here is the code based on your site

```css
a#launch-tab-4:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    background: #00aa00;
}
a#development-tab-4:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 126px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    background: #eeaaff;
}
a#planning-tab-4:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    background: #00eeff;
}
a#brainstorming-tab-4:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    background: #000;
}
```

it should look like this 
[image: screen shoot]

replace the colors with your images and you may adjust the width and height

Comment: cannot add the class

Comment: sorry, use the ID, answer updated,
each of your **a tag** contain an ID, so just duplicate the code for each one

Comment: yes, CSS need to be adjusted more ... can you show us the link of the page so i can give you the final code ?

Comment: goo(dot)gl/vQSbpm , Thanks for helping

Comment: the site is under coming soon page

Comment: Fixed !!, Its now live

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154825/discussion-between-daiyan-and-temani-afif).

Comment: Can you please check icons are still really far and not aligned?

Comment: add this : **background-position: center;**

Comment: Thank you so much , Worked like a charm..
Just one last question , Can i make it bigger and can add green color on hover ?

Comment: to make it bigger add this **background-size: 50%;** you can increase/decrease the value until you get what you want. For the color i don't think since it's an image

Answer (score -1):

Try adding style *background-size:cover* or *background-size:contain*

I hope this helps